# What's the difference between two queries fetching same results where one query uses inner join and another uses left join?

Tags: postgresql

I needed to write a query to answer the following questions:

> Create a list that shows all payments including the payment_id, amount, and the film category (name) plus the total amount that was made in this category. Order the results ascendingly by the category (name) and as second order criterion by the payment_id ascendingly.
>
> What is the total revenue of the category 'Action' and what is the lowest payment_id in that category 'Action'?

So I wrote the following query and got the answer:

```sql
select payment_id, name,(select sum(p.amount) from payment p
                              inner join rental r
                              on p.rental_id = r.rental_id
                              inner join inventory i
                              on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
                              inner join film_category fc
                              on fc.film_id = i.film_id
                              inner join category c
                              on c.category_id = fc.category_id
                              group by c.name
                      having name = 'Action')
from (select p.payment_id, c.name, sum(p.amount) from payment p
inner join rental r
on p.rental_id = r.rental_id
inner join inventory i
on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
inner join film_category fc
on fc.film_id = i.film_id
inner join category c
on c.category_id = fc.category_id
group by c.name, p.payment_id) as new_column
order by name asc, payment_id asc
```

However, the solution given for the problem had a slighty different query:

```sql
SELECT
title,
amount,
name,
payment_id,
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM payment p
LEFT JOIN rental r
ON r.rental_id=p.rental_id
LEFT JOIN inventory i
ON i.inventory_id=r.inventory_id
LEFT JOIN film f
ON f.film_id=i.film_id
LEFT JOIN film_category fc
ON fc.film_id=f.film_id
LEFT JOIN category c1
ON c1.category_id=fc.category_id
WHERE c1.name=c.name)
FROM payment p
LEFT JOIN rental r
ON r.rental_id=p.rental_id
LEFT JOIN inventory i
ON i.inventory_id=r.inventory_id
LEFT JOIN film f
ON f.film_id=i.film_id
LEFT JOIN film_category fc
ON fc.film_id=f.film_id
LEFT JOIN category c
ON c.category_id=fc.category_id
ORDER BY name
```

What's the difference between the two queries and which one is more optimized and why?

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Not sure why you're hardcoding `having name = 'Action'`? That's an obvious difference to start with

Comment: Really neither query is well-optimised. You probably should use a window function instead of the subquery to make it less repetitive, i.e. `SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY c.category_id)`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Please go [here](https://dbfiddle.uk) and construct a fiddle with sample data and your desired result.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion the second query is likely more optimized because it uses LEFT JOINs to ensure all payments are included, places the subquery within the main query, and includes necessary columns like 'title' and 'amount'. However, actual performance can depend on the database schema, indexes, and data volume, so testing both queries with real data is advisable.